# Skype for business: is there anyway to make chat rooms function more like Slack?

Tags: lync, lync-2013, skype-for-business, slack

Is there anyway to set up chatrooms in Skype for business (previously Lync) so that they are sticky (always open) and will notify all the members when a new message is written? Something like writing @channel in Slack.